# Significato di "occhi sbaraglianti" (o "sbarluscenti") in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, regional

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> E nemmeno è capitato che mi sia rimirato dentro il culo di una padella lustra che mi faceva da specchio,
>   cosí che a guardarmi: «Ohi, che **occhi sbaraglianti** di allegria che spargono luce felice da ogni luogo [felicità in ogni luogo]! Sono proprio simpatico, splendente! Vado a fare il giullare!»

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "occhi sbaraglianti". Ho cercato alla voce "sbaragliare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho saputo trovare nulla che abbia senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

**Aggiornamento:**

Per si è di aiuto, nella versione originale in dialetto (ragusano?)<sup>(1)</sup> appare "ögi sbarluscénti".

<sup>(1) Per quanto racconta Fo nel prologo a questa storia, mi è sembrato che il dialetto della versione originale fosse ragusano, ma non ne sono sicura. Può darsi che ci sia anche qualche dialetto del Nord d'Italia. Il prologo comincia cosí: "Questo è un testo ragusano, raccolto nel secolo scorso da un amico e collaboratore di Pitré, il famoso ricercatore di Palermo che ha pubblicato una mole incredibile di documentazione sulla tradizione popolare della Sicilia. Piú tardi mi sono capitati per le mani frammenti di una giullarata che svolgeva lo stesso tema, provenienti dal Nord d’Italia,esattamente da Cremona. Ho innestato questi ultimi 
nel testo ragusano e ne è venuta fuori la «conta» che vi presento". In una nota si spiega che "conta" significa "favola o fabulazione popolare". E finisce cosí: "Ma quel discorso è meglio che lo ascoltiate direttamente e per intero nel linguaggio originale" (si riferisce alla versione originale del racconto).</sup>

Comment: Credo che in questo caso sia utilizzato come "abbaglianti" o "scintillanti" :) 
Nei dialetti settentrionali si utilizza anche il termine "sbarluccicare" o "sberluccicare" (https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=SBERLUCCICARE100)

Comment: Fo è stato tradito da un'assonanza.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi:  Nella versione originale in dialetto è "sbarluscénti", quindi penso che tu abbia ragione.

Comment: @Charo se desideri, la aggiungo come risposta

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Sí, puoi farlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credo che in questo caso sia utilizzato come "abbaglianti" o "scintillanti"; nei dialetti settentrionali si utilizza anche il termine *"sbarluccicare"* o *"sberluccicare"*.

Da notare che lo stesso Dario Fo, nella versione in dialetto, utilizza *"sbarluscénti"*.

Infatti, nel [vocabolario milanese - italiano di Francesco Cherubini](https://www.google.es/url?q=http://scans.library.utoronto.ca/pdf/4/30/vocabolariomilan00cheruoft/vocabolariomilan00cheruoft.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjsxM3v6NTYAhVH1RQKHct8BhIQFggZMAc&usg=AOvVaw3Nmb7-RzI-3W29ygap_HWG) (1814) si trova:

> **Sbarlusent** (*che anche dicesi* **Barlusent**) *Rilucente. Splendente. Risplendente. Lucente. Dilucciante. Luccicante. Micante. Lampegiante.*

E nel [dizionario milanese - italiano di Cletto Arrighi](https://books.google.es/books?id=unXLSjhepGUC&pg=PA648&lpg=PA648) (1977) si legge:

> **Sbarlusent,** Splendente. *«Gh'era el ramm in cusinna sbarlusent»*: «C'era in cucina il rame appeso luccicantissimo o rilucente».

Anche nel libro [Maeta ch'al piova (Immagina che piova). Una proposta di cultura e di dialetto e di cultura bogognese](https://www.google.es/url?q=http://www.comune.bogogno.no.it/FileDownload.asp%3FT%3D9%26I%3D27151%26IdCom%3D9&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi2yveF-NTYAhXLvhQKHZuMDSk4ChAWCBYwBQ&usg=AOvVaw04YdaOLYf1UkL8zG0ahU_i) appare:

> **Sbarlušént**     Luccicante

Comment: Infatti, il termine "sbarluscente" appare in molti siti web in italiano, in particolare in alcuni che parlano di Milano o del milanese, come [questo](https://www.forumsalute.it/community/forum_42_alla_ricerca_di_un_bimbo/thrd_28571_rituali_bislacchi_del_po_75.html), in cui si leggi "sbarluscente (oltremodo brillante, per chi non è milanese)".

Comment: Comunque, come accennato da @egreg, penso che in questo caso il significato si sia "lost in translation".